# Windows 10, SSD and SATA hard drive letters missing from Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, drive-letter

**Symptoms :**

- All hard drives are accessible. Everything looks fine in Directory Opus.
  But in Windows Explorer, and in the system windows that open with actions such as File>Open, File>Save As, etc. : only USB hard drives are visible on the left pane.
- All internal SSD and SATA hard drives are invisible.
- I can access any hard drive, any folder, any file perfectly fine if I write down the drive letter manually or the path. But even then, current browsed folder/drive won't expand to my position in the drive's folder structure as it usually do.
- "This PC" is gone. If I access it manually all it shows me on the right pane is "This folder is empty".
- All I see in Windows Explorer (Left Pane) is Quick Access, Desktop shortcuts, USB hard drives. Everything else is gone.
- Some softwares cannot open a file from its usual position in the drive. I get messages such as "file cannot be found". But if I move the file to the root, then I can open it, work on it, save it just fine. And move it back where it was manually when I'm done...

**Things I tested :**

- In Disk Management all is fine. "Action>Rescan Disks" had no effect. All drives are healthy and have their usual drive letter assigned.
- I tried changing a drive's letter. I could see that change in Dopus, but no effect on Windows Explorer.
- In Windows Explorer > FolderOptions it's all as usual : no system file/folder, no empty drive, etc is set to "hidden"; "Show drive letters" is ticked.
- I ran Windows 10 hardware troubleshooter but it went on without any error. All was "fine".
- I checked the Registry (Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices) and all mounted devices have their drive letter assigned normally.
- In Device Manager, I tried to update all Disk Drive drivers, but they were up to date.
- I tried to restart in Safe Mode : same problem.
- I ran a few system scans with different apps, but I have Bitdefender Total Security and my system has been free of any malware, virus, etc for many years.
- I did not install anything new recently as I'm a 3D modeler for 25+ years and tend to always have the same collection of softwares.
- I restarted in safe mode. CMD admin : I ran an sfc /scannow  : "[...] no integrity violations". Also ran a chkdsk on the main SSD : nothing corrupted.

**Other symptoms I noticed around the same time and that are probably linked ? :**

- I always press Windows key and type the first letters of an app to start it. Recently when I type I feel that the response is a tad longer. I noticed a "search indexing is turned off". Not sure I ever turned it on as I use Voidtools Everything, but there seem to be something going on with that.
- Services.msc (Computer Management) > Services : WSearch "Failed to read description. Error Code 2". If I try to start it manually, it does not start (Error 5 : Access is denied).
- Control Panel > Indexing Options : "Indexing is not running". A click on "Rebuild"(Deletes and rebuilds index) does absolutely nothing at all. I can't specify a location for the index as the button "Select New (Location)" is greyed out...

---

I don't know what to do anymore. But this causes some serious issues as some files attached to my work (textures of a 3D object, etc) are now appearing as missing in some 3D softwares. Even though the files are there, can be seen and opened in Dopus, ACDSee, even in Windows Explorer if I manually write down the path. But the missing drive letters cause problems in some programs that can't find files that are definitely there, in a ghost drive letter.

Just an example : RizomUV cannot open an fbx if it's inside a subfolder of those "missing" drives (error message along those lines : "cannot find the file"). But if I move the file to the root of that "ghost" drive, then RizomUV sees it.

This issue is very recent. Probably related to a Windows Update. I guess the solution is somewhere in the registry ?...

Any idea would be much welcomed ;)
Thanks !

Comment: Please don't include personal information like email address or phone numbers in your posts. If you want to have them available put them in your [profile](https://superuser.com/users/774131/hansolocambo?tab=profile)

Comment: Use `regedit` and navigate to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`. If you see a value named `NoDrives`, then delete it and reboot.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc for the feedback. I checked the registry and sadly there is no NoDrives value in 

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer